# Show the complete build command in Keil

Tags: build, command, keil, armcc

(Related question, never answered: [Show complete commands during build in Keil uVision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73724175/show-complete-commands-during-build-in-keil-uvision))

Hi,

I am using µVision V5.38.0.0 with the compiler armcc V5.06 update 7 (build 960).
Below, you can see "compiling XXX.c...". I would like the complete build command to be shown.

[Before build command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z69F3.png)

As you can see in the screenshot, I try --show_cmdline option, but it throws an error (see the picture).

How can I show the complete build command (for each file)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to show the full command in the output window.

The closest thing that I've been able to get is to use the 'Create Batch File' option. On a full rebuild, this will build a batch file that has all the commands used to build the project.

KEIL creates ".__i" files that it uses in the command line. These files are referenced when building and contain the full command with arguments that is used for a given source file.

Below is an example of what could be in the batch file.
[image]

And this is what the contents of a given ".__i" file might look like.
[image]

Note that this is just the output of a quick project that I have at hand and is for the ARMClang compiler and probably for a different processor. Depending on the project settings that you have enabled, the arguments and other output may appear different.

That being said, I wish they would update KEIL to have an option to output the full commands and have a complete log with the full commands.